# How Can I read From Line number() to line Starts with in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, readline

Let's say I have text file like this

```
<pre>----------------

    hPa     m      C 
---------------------
 1004.0     28   13.6
 1000.0     62   16.2
  998.0     79   17.2
  992.0    131   18.0
<pre>----------------
Sometext here

 1000.0     10   10.6
 1000.0     10   11.2
  900.0     10   12.2
  900.0    100   13.0
<aaa>----------------
```

**How Can I Create Array in C# that reads text file from line number 5 (`1004.0`) to  just before line that starts with string `<pre>-`**

**I used   string[] lines = `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filepath);`
To make each line in the array
The problem is I want only numbers of first section in the array in order to separate them later to another 3 arrays (hPa, m, C) .**

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want us to write it for you?

Comment: [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) and [String.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms131452.aspx) might be a start.

Comment: I suspect you've already found the answer.. you can't just read the one line in a file, you need to just continue to loop until you get to your starting point

Comment: Also, an array of what? A complete line per array cell? An 3-dimensional array, with each dimension holding a different value (hPa, m, C)?

Comment: I used   string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filepath);
To make each line in the array

The problem is I want only numbers of first section in the array in order to separate them  to another 3 arrays (hPa, m, C) .
Thank you all for replying

Comment: If you have an array of all the lines, then you can use that to further filter the data (admittedly, it's not elegant to read a 10MB file to get only 4 numbers, but how large is your file and how much data you need to get from it is another thing). Also, are the numbers separated by regular spaces or tabs?

Comment: @Shaamaan file size is less than 1MB
numbers are not separated by regular spaces but every Column have fixed width .. So I figured out that I will use something like this lines[i].Substring(0, 7).Trim(); (to get values from first Column Witch its width = 7)

Comment: You could also use `Split(' ')` and then process the first non-empty result from each line. There's possibly a thousand ways to do this. :P

Comment: @Shaamaan Thank you for you answer it helped me a lot
I am still trying to do it but I have some difficulties 
here an example for the text file I want to process
http://pastebin.com/FFQH3NMw

Comment: I'm not going to write your app for you. ;P In the file you linked the number of initial lines that need to be ignored differs. At this point, I'd assume that number might change, and I'd actively search for the start of the table (a line which starts with "<pre>-" seems to indicate a start of a table), then skip a few more lines (headers), and then you can read the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. It's probably way more complicated than it should be, but that should give you an idea of possible mechanisms to further refine your data.

```
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
        List<double> results = new List<double>();
        foreach (var line in lines.Skip(4))
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("<pre>"))
                break;
            Regex numberReg = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d){0,1}");  //will find any number ending in ".X" - it's primitive, and won't work for something like 0.01, but no such data showed up in your example
            var result = numberReg.Matches(line).Cast<Match>().FirstOrDefault();  //use only the first number from each line. You could use Cast<Match>().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault to get the second, and so on...
            if (result != null)
                results.Add(Convert.ToDouble(result.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  //Note the use of InvariantCulture, otherwise you may need to worry about , or . in your numbers
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_PATH);

int skipLines = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < skipLines; i++)
{
    file.ReadLine();
}

// Do what you want here.
```

Comment: wouldn't `File.ReadAllLines(Filepath).Skip(5)` be easier?

Comment: @I4V That would work for first problem (starting array from 6th line)
The other problem I want array ends befor "<pre>"